# CakePHP 2 and Croogo with Basic Authentication for REST

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

When trying to login via REST, I simply added:

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isXML()) {
     $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic');
}
```

To my plugins AppController. When i request via a rest client i get:
DbAcl::check() - Failed ARO/ACO node lookup in permissions check.

With my user object dumped. Strange, it seems like it's logging me in but not reading permissions correctly?

Answer (score 0):

When i added:

```
$this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
```

and implemented the isAuthorized method:

```
public function isAuthorized($user) {
    if (isset($user['role_id']) && $user['role_id'] == 1) { 
         return true; //Admin can access every action   
    } 
    return false; // The rest don't 
}
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is one fundamental thing here that you seem to be missing: Authentication and Authorization **are two different things**.

**Authentication** is the process of identifying users by provided credentials and ensuring that users are who they say they are. This is generally done using an username and password.

**Authorization** is the process of ensuring that the current user is allowed to access a 
specific resource.

The error you were getting is an Authorization error and from it I call tell that you're trying to use [ACL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/access-control-lists.html). Your fix to the issue is to configure Controller based Authorization andthrough it allow the admin to access everything. [Controller Based Authorization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what) is not related to ACL authorization. Check the links provided.

The [AuthComponent](http://api20.cakephp.org/class/auth-component) implements 3 different types of [Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html):

> FormAuthenticate - allows you to authenticate users based on form POST
>   data. Usually this is a login form that users enter information into.
>
> BasicAuthenticate - allows you to authenticate users using Basic HTTP
>   authentication.
>
> DigestAuthenticate - allows you to authenticate users using Digest
>   HTTP authentication.

If you're developing a [REST service](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html) I'd recommend using [Digest Authentication](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#using-digest-and-basic-authentication-for-logging-in) as the "best to have" but it'd still depend on what you're logging in.